# Data URI that represents JavaScript or HTML that outputs an image?

Tags: javascript, html, uri

I was looking into encoding and SVG then using `data:image/svg+xml;base64,ENCODED SVG`. When I wondered if I could use a data URI for JavaScript or  HTML code (not just `data:text/html` because my html uses JS to produce an image)
I have done quite a bit of research, but `data:text/html` is all I have come close to figuring this out.
I appreciate any and all help you can provide!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can't you just use inline javascript or, if you absolutely need the Javascript to be external, use the text/javascript MIME type?

Comment: Inline JS would be great, how would I go about that?